# Azure IoT Plug and play app on Android phone not sharing Geolocation and shows N/A

Tags: geolocation, azure-iot-central, iotplugandplay, androidphone

I am trying to use my smartphone as device using Azure IoT plug and play app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/quick-deploy-iot-central

My Iphone is able to share all the details including geo location.
However I am facing issue with my Android phone, its not showing Geolocation on the mobile app.

I have given all the necessary permission including location from my Android phone settings, still not showing the geolocation co-ordinates and shows N/A.

Tried to find solution by doing extensive google search, but couldn't find any. If anyone has a solution please share.

Below is snapshot of my android phone screen for your review so you know the exact issue.
It is highlighted in yellow.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you enabled the location permission to the App in your Mobile Settings?

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. I even tried with other Android phones. Still getting the same issue.

Comment: Ok, I'm also seeing the same result. I even tried with commands but its not showing. I'll try to find the resolution and update. Documentation Image also doesn't show up Location.

Comment: Yup, its only with Android phone. Iphone app is working as per documents. Thanks.

Comment: @KrunalPatil, in the case of exploring IoT PnP Device with Azure IoT Central App can be helped also an android apk https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5322753/Azure-IoT-Central-Tester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KrunalPatil Looks like there was an issue with the earlier version 1.0.7. Please un-install and re-install the IoT PnP application from app store again and try. The latest version is 1.1.0

You can find the version on your application. Goto-> Settings on Top Right -> Version

I've updated the Android IoT PnP application to latest version 1.1.0 and I am able to see the location on both application and Azure Portal.

[image]

[image]